# Powershell function with input as two params that are arrays

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I've tried searching for this problem but haven't found anything helpful.

I'm trying to get a Powershell Function to loop over an array of strings.  My twist is I'm trying to add a second array.  The first array has the days of the week.  The second array is a timestamp for example `2015-01-19`

What I have working so far is below.  I'm aware that using `Get-Date` then formatting that to what works (by adding and formatting the results) might be easier, I'm open to suggestions.  -Thanks, I really do appreciate the assistance!

```psh
Function My-Test{
    param(
        [string[]]$arr,
        [string[]]$arr2
    )
    Foreach($day in $arr){
        "$day is the best day to read something."
    }
    Foreach($var2 in $arr2){
        echo $arr2
    }
}

$days = @("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
$var2 = @("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")

My-Test -arr $days -arr2 $var2
```

## Test below

```psh
$array = @(
 ("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
 ("2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-01-03","2015-01-04","2015-01-05","2015-01-06","2015-01-07")
 )
$array[0][2]
```

The `$array` does not return the two properties, it returns `Wednesday`

Comment: You should simplify the code to isolate the question you're asking.  The problem you've stated has nothing to do with IE.

Comment: Also, show what you've tried with the second array parameter.

Comment: No, you are correct IE has nothing to do with this question however it's part of my script.  Question has been edited.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't error, and it gives reasonable output.  What output were you expecting?

Comment: Apologies, hit enter before clearing the comment.  Powershell seems simple but I still struggle.  I'm trying to get a loop in a function that outputs values from two (or more) arrays.

Comment: In your second Foreach, you should `echo $var2`, you are echoing the entire array.

Comment: Thank  you @MickyBalladelli because scripting is just not my thing!

Comment: Follow up question, how can I get Powershell to return these two values on the same line?  I keep thinking I could use one array and only return the index I want or would that be too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the followup question.

You could return the two values (I assume $arr and $arr2) in either a single array or in an array containing two arrays:

```
Function My-Test{
    param(
        [string[]]$arr,
        [string[]]$arr2 
    )
    Foreach($day in $arr){
       write-host "$day is the best day to read something."   
    }
    Foreach($var2 in $arr2){
        write-host $var2
    }

    $ret = $arr+$arr2
    return $ret
}

$days = @("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
$var2 = @("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")

$ret = My-Test -arr $days -arr2 $var2
```

Then `$ret.Count` is 14 and $ret contains the combined $arr + $arr2

Other possibility is to create an array of arrays, or a two dimentional array:

```
$ret = @()
$ret += ,$arr
$ret += ,$arr2
return $ret
```

In this case `$ret[0]` contains the weekdays, and `$ret[0][0]` is Monday, `$ret[0][1]` is Tuesday, etc. and `$ret[1]` contains the second array.

PS. You don't need to write `return` you could simply write `$ret` as it's implicit that you are returning that value, but it's simpler to explain with that example in my opinion. 
In fact you don't even need to create a `$ret` variable, you could just write

```
@($arr,$arr2)
```

**EDIT**

You can only access elements in an array one at a time.

Lets look at your new multidimentional array

```
$array = @(
 ("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
 ("2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-01-03","2015-01-04","2015-01-05","2015-01-06","2015-01-07")
 )
```

Let's see what `$array[0]` contains:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

So `$array[0][0]` is the first element of this array, Monday, `$array[0][1]` is the second, Tuesday, etc.

If we look at the second array:

```
$array[1]
```

It contains:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
2015-01-06
2015-01-07
```

The first element for the second array is `$array[1][0]`, 2015-01-01, the second is `$array[1][1]`, 2015-01-02, etc.

Comment: I tried the multidimensional array approach but this quickly went over my head.  Edited question with multidimensional array code.

Comment: And that means I could do this `($array[0][4] + " " + $array[1][4])` to get the output `Friday 2015-01-05`

Comment: OK I've got stuck adding this to an existing script.  This script takes a T-SQL query and outputs the results as an Excel spreadsheet.  I'm trying to run 7 queries and create 1 spreadsheet containing 7 worksheets.  I just worked out the code to run the 7 queries but I get 7 spreadsheets.  I've got the code to add a new worksheet to an existing workbook but can't figure out how to pass two arrays on two parameters to this function.

Comment: I would recommend writing a new question, and provide an up to date version of your script, and the desired results.

Comment: Things are working as is however I'm running into the Zombie Excel proc that won't close.  If you open the spreadsheet then close it, it'll close but I want the script to do so (Powershell!!! You clean up after yourself!) but the code is far from optimized.  But I'm curious to see what to community thinks.